How to copy color of a range in another work sheet to the active work sheet
I have the address of a cell in another work sheet ($B$1 for example); the color of this cell is red (for example)
How can I copy the color of this cell into a cell in the active work sheet?
I have to repeat the same referencing approximately 10 other work sheets. I am using an input box to define the reference sheet
Is there a way to use the targeted work sheet names as a variable and use INDIRECT to copy the color?
I used VLOOKUP with INDIRECT to return the cell address in another worksheet, for example the value returned is $B$1

Something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Interior.Color = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").Interior.Color will change the colour of the cell in Sheet1!B1 to whatever color the cell in Sheet2!B3 is.

Excel can't change the formatting of a cell from a formula in the cell, so indirect and vlookup won't help you, I'm afraid. However, you can use conditional formatting; if the formatting of a cell in the other worksheet is conditional, then you can use the same condition in this worksheet. Otherwise you'll have to use VBA, as Darren mentioned.

If you have existing code it's best to include it in your question.

Thanks Darren that helped me a lot. Is there a way that I can use an input box as a prompt for "Sheet2" in your VBA coding. I'm not an expert in VBA coding
